# Exporting post names in SQL, then reusing them [Wordpress/Woocommerce/SQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to fill the description of around 100 Products in a Woocommerce Wordpress site via SQL, however I am fairly new to the SQL language and facing some troubles. I have already figured out how to fill the description, like so:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt = '%description goes here%' WHERE post_type = 'product'
```

However, here is where I'm facing problems: I am trying to GET all the Product Names (wp_posts with type product) and want to re-use them in the above mentioned update query. As a very basic example, i would like to try to set all descriptions to "This is the description for %productTitle%".
I already have something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
post_title
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'product'
```

But how do i save the returned titles in variables to reuse with my first query?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, here is where I'm facing problems: I am trying to GET all the
>   Product Names (wp_posts with type product) and want to re-use them in
>   the above mentioned update query.

You don't need *re-use* any data. If you want update that column massively, you can use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to concatenate strings.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt = CONCAT('This is the description for ',productTitle) WHERE post_type = 'product'
```

Comment: That's a lot simpler then i expected. It doesn't work though, getting an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_type = 'product' AND (post_excerpt <> CONCAT('This ' at line 1.  I'm using a server with MySQL  5.7.14 and PHP  5.6.26

Comment: Error message is a little bit different from your Question, Could you paste your SQL sentence?

Comment: Sorry,  made the mistake of forgetting the select query before your query. Your answer is completely right and worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Good luck ;)